# Passing values to a dynamically created function call inside a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

How to set the subscription so the `date2Handler` is called with the respective date1 and date2 values from a month on which the date1 change occurred?

Currently, changing date1 value in any of the month calls the date2Handler with the "month" which was set to the `newSubItem` most recently. In the example bellow, the function triggered via the subscription on `dataViewModel.agenda.months[0].date1` effectively calls `data2Handler(dataViewModel.agenda.months[2].date1, dataViewModel.agenda.months[2].date2)` instead of `data2Handler(dataViewModel.agenda.months[0].date1, dataViewModel.agenda.months[0].date2)` (see the indexes of the months array).

How to elegantly fix it?

In the real application, the months might be popped and pushed dynamically several times during the page life time.

Model

```
var dataModel = {
    months: [],
    agenda: {
        months: [],
    },
};

var observableModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(dataModel);
ko.applyBindings(observableModel, document.getElementById("rootView"));
```

Subcribing to change event

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    dataViewModel.months.push(ko.mapping.fromJS({
        monthId: null
    }));
    var newSubItem = ko.mapping.fromJS({
        date1: null,
        date2: null
    });
    newSubItem.date1.subscribe(function() {
        date2Handler(newSubItem.date1, newSubItem.date2)
    });
    dataViewModel.agenda.months.push(newSubItem);
}

function date2Handler(date1, date2) {
    if (date2() == null) {
        date2(date1());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the asynchronous aspect of your `newSubItem.date1.subscribe` call, when executed, the `newSubItem` is in fact the last value of your loop.

To correct this, you may need to wrap this call in a self executing anonymous function to 'freeze' your variable in time :

```
(function (item) {
    newSubItem.date1.subscribe(function() {
        date2Handler(item.date1, item.date2)
    });
}(newSubItem));
```

It should fix your issue.